# Formula auditing - error checking for a specific region

Tags: excel, formula

I would like to ask whether it is possible to check inconsistent formula for a specific region.

In my case, col D and col E contain different sets of formula.

I just want to ensure that all formula in col E are consistent.

Is it possible to do so??

Comment: What do you mean by "consistent"?

Comment: Yes it is very easy :) `EXcel Options` ~~> `Error Checking Rules` ~~> `Formulas Inconsistent with other formulas in the region` Set the checkbox to True. You will get a green triangle if the formulas are inconsistent

Comment: Re @Floris : "consistent" means D1 ="sum(a1+b1)" D2 ="sum(a2+b2)" D2 ="sum(a3+b3)"

Comment: RE @SiddharthRout What u suggest will do error checking for whole worksheet ... but I only want to do error checking for specific col

Comment: Yes but let it do. I believe your main issue is to identify if Col E has consistent formulas or not and the method that I suggested will tell you that :)

Comment: By using that method , the prog will also compare with D1 and E1 and suggest that there is an error

Comment: If it is a one time thing then simply create a copy of the sheet and delete the formulas in col D and Col F and then check for inconsistent formulas?

Comment: Or would you like a VBA Solution?

Comment: Eric, the way you describe "consistent", I don't see why you wouldn't just drag the formula again (after defining the necessary locks). Any inconsistencies will automatically disappear. Isn't that what you mean?

Comment: I agree with @KimGysen - copying formulas down column E seems the easiest - but it's not really "auditing"... There's a clever trick: if you select the first formula in the column, and **double-click** the little "drag" box in the corner, it will replicate a consistent formula all the way down the column. Super quick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way.

Let's say your worksheet looks like this

[image]

Now Paste this code in a module and run it. It will tell you which cells have inconsistent formulas. See below screenshot

I have commented the code so that you will not have any problem understanding it. If you do simply ask :)

```
Option Explicit

Sub GetInConsCells()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range, cl As Range, errCells As Range
    Dim ErrorCells As String
    Dim lRow As Long

    '~~> Create a temp copy of the sheet
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Copy After:=Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    With ws
        '~~> Clear Col D and Col F Contents
        .Range("D:D,F:F").ClearContents

        '~~> Find the last row of col E
        lRow = .Range("E" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        '~~> Set your range
        Set rng = Range("E1:E" & lRow)

        '~~> Check if the cells have inconsistent formulas
        For Each cl In rng
            If cl.Errors(xlInconsistentFormula).Value Then
                If errCells Is Nothing Then
                    Set errCells = cl
                Else
                    Set errCells = Union(cl, errCells)
                End If
            End If
        Next cl

        '~~> Display relevant message
        If Not errCells Is Nothing Then
            ErrorCells = errCells.Address
            MsgBox "Formulas in cells " & ErrorCells & " are inconsitent"
        Else
            MsgBox "All Formulas are consistent"
        End If
    End With

    '~~> Delete temp sheet
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ws.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A quick and pragmatic way would be to use another column (temporarily):
Assuming you want to check that each cell in column E has the formula `=SUM(A1:D1)`, simply enter the formula `=(SUM(A1:D1)-E1` in another column. Then select the column and filter for `FALSE`- this will give you all the formulas that have different results!